# swiperjs button click problem into carousel slide

Tags: javascript, frontend, swiper.js

I have created a carousel using swiperjs. on every slide there have a button. when i clicking the button on slide it is moving to first slide suddenly. but it should not move.

```
`https://codepen.io/latifur/pen/mdpeJPK`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd3pM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftlMq.png)

Answer (score 0):

When we click on any link or button in swiper slide, the swiper slide of gets active and we see it sliding. To prevent this , there is an attribute 'a11y', set to false as:

```
{
  slidesPerView: 3,
  a11y: false,
}
```